# Why the size of viewport for a swing app vary once I vary the size of window?

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

I am trying to apply scrollPane in my swing application.
But I can't see my scrollbar once I vary the size of window.

I know there are 9 component in a scrollpane : viewport,2 header, 2 scrollbar and 4 corner.But when I set the color of border to red(which applied to viewport), the result showing that the only element in my window is merely the viewport.(As the red border is all around the window.)

Here is my code.

```
package swingDemo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;;

public class ScrollDemo1 extends JFrame{

    public ScrollDemo1() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(50,0,1000,100);
        label.setText("Do you want to have a coffee together?");

        JButton button = new JButton("Of course!");
        button.setBounds(10,60,150,50);
        button.addActionListener(e -> label.setText("Well, let's go!"));
        JButton button2 = new JButton("No,sorry.");
        button2.setBounds(170,60,150,50);
        button2.addActionListener(e -> label.setText("Well, let's go!"));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10,10,10,10);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
        setBounds(10,10,40,60);
        setTitle("Dating Robot");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ScrollDemo1 obj = new ScrollDemo1();
            obj.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

}
```

I would like to see the scrollbar. Anyone Please? Thank You!

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` is likely the problem. Null layouts screw particularly with scroll panes. More generally: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: BTW - given the nature of this GUI, I'd use a `JOptionPane` instead. It would neither have, no need, a scroll pane (or attention to layouts, sizing & a few other things).

Comment: Well, I agree with you. Having no layout manager is the source of problems as I saw on stackoverflow. I will go and learn it. Thanks! If anyone have the idea that this problem is not caused by the layout, please do tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code, and this example should resolve some of them.

The main problem was caused by setting the layout manager to `null`. When the scroll pane tried to get the size of the contained panel, it wasn't able to get a good answer, so it couldn't show scroll bars.

You may have noticed that everything was actually on the screen, just that it was all squeezed up. By setting the size, everything is visible.

By commenting out the `setLayout(null)`, I probably broke the visual layout you intended, so adjust to taste. It will be better to use one of the layout managers though.

The call to `scrollPane.setViewportView(panel)` is unnecessary, as that already was handled in the constructor when you called `new JScrollPane(panel)`. This probably was benign, but it's these kinds of redundant calls that sometimes cause Swing weirdness, as Swing often registers listeners and such behind the scenes.

Finally, I added a call to `setDefaultCloseOperation` so that the app will exit when clicking the window-close button.

I hope this helps!

```
package swingDemo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

;

public class ScrollDemo1 extends JFrame {

  public ScrollDemo1() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setBounds(50, 0, 1000, 100);
    label.setText("Do you want to have a coffee together?");

    JButton button = new JButton("Of course!");
    button.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 50);
    button.addActionListener(e -> label.setText("Well, let's go!"));
    JButton button2 = new JButton("No,sorry.");
    button2.setBounds(170, 60, 150, 50);
    button2.addActionListener(e -> label.setText("Well, let's go!"));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
    panel.add(button2);
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);
    // This causes problems:
//    panel.setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    add(scrollPane);
    // This is redundent:
//    scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
    setBounds(10, 10, 40, 60);
    setTitle("Dating Robot");
    // Some initial size (or "pack") is needed to make it big enough to see
    setSize(500, 500);
    // This makes the app exit cleanly when closing the frame
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      ScrollDemo1 obj = new ScrollDemo1();
      obj.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```